# Find bounding box for CALayer to draw into graphics context

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation

I have a `CALayer` with multiple sublayers. `clipsToBounds` is `NO` (default). I want to draw the complete content of the `CALayer` (incl. all sublayers) into an image context. For that I need to determine how big the context needs to be. Is there a method on `CALayer` to retrieve the required size for a graphics context, in order to fit all content in? (i.e. also the content that is beyond the layer's bounds)

Comment: how do you draw CALayer in Graphics context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the bounding box as the union of the layer and all of its sublayers.

```
CGRect boundingBox = myLayer.bounds;
for (CALayer *sublayer in myLayer.sublayers) {
    boundingBox = CGRectUnion(boundingBox, sublayer.frame);
}
```

This works because `CGRectUnion` returns:

> The smallest rectangle that completely contains both of the source rectangles.

so by doing the union of the bounding box and each layer you get a rectangle is the smallest rectangle that completely contains all sublayers (and the layer itself).

---

Note that the `bounds` was used for the layer itself while `frame` was used for the sublayers. This is because the bounds is in the layers own coordinate system while the frame is in the parents coordinate system. This means that frame on the sublayers is in `myLayer`'s coordinate system.

Also note that this isn't a recursive solution so if the sublayers have sublayers of their own that extent outside of their bounds, then this solution won't account for that.

Comment: That's much nicer than my idea! Clear and simple.

Comment: @David Rönnqvist: Let's say there's a UIImageView that is smaller than its image and the content mode of the view set to UIViewContentModeCenter. If maskToBounds is set to NO, your answer above would wrongly report the UIImageView's bounds and the image would be clipped?!

Comment: @camimvogelsang is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Sorry, yes it was a question. It seems that calculating the union of the frames/bounds as you suggested would result in a wrong bounding box because it doesn't take `maskToBounds=NO` into consideration? Or put differently, how would you calculate the bounding box for a single layer without any sublayers that draws outside of its bounds when `maskToBounds=NO`. The area outside of the layer's bounds would be visible when added to the layer hierarchy but would be clipped by the above bounding box calculation it seems.

Comment: @camimvogelsang That's a very different case than what your original question. How exactly are you drawing outside of the bounds? It is possible that this would be a better fit for a new question (that would link back to this question)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist: Hm, isn't it just a simpler case of the original question? If you take the original question above and assume there's just one layer (backing a UIImageView) with no sublayers, your calculation would return the bounds of the layer/view and seems to dismiss/clip away the "overflowing" image content that otherwise would be shown (because `maskToBounds=NO`)?

Comment: I can't think of an easy way. You would probably have to make a special case for image views where you look at the size of the image and the content mode of the view

Answer (score 1):

No - the graphics context has no size, so there is no such method. You have to do it yourself. 
You need to iterate over all sublayers and find all max & min values for width/height;

You need something like that:

```
CGRect layerRect = [self layer].frame;

CGFloat minX = CGRectGetMinX(layerRect);
CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(layerRect);
CGFloat minY = CGRectGetMinY(layerRect);
CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(layerRect);

for(CALayer *sublayer in [[self layer] sublayers])
{
    CGRect sublayerRect = sublayer.frame;

    minX = MIN(minX, CGRectGetMinX(sublayerRect));
    maxX = MAX(maxX, CGRectGetMaxX(sublayerRect));

    minY = MIN(minY, CGRectGetMinY(sublayerRect));
    maxY = MAX(maxY, CGRectGetMinY(sublayerRect));
}

CGSize imageSize = (CGSize){maxX - minX, maxY - minY};
```

Comment: Just as with the `bounds`, the `frame` won't give the actual bounding box of the content. Think of a `CALayer` where content flows out of the `bounds`, and `clipToMask` is set to `NO`.

Comment: And that's exactly what happens in my answer.